# PHP mysqli printing array issue

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have an issue with PHP and mysqli, as im not really familiar with the coding language i have this issue: When i try to fill the array from row 1 to 8 the only return i get when i do `print_r $items` the result is 8. Not 1 to 8. Can someone help me ?

Code

```
$gebruiker = $_SESSION['user'];

$query = "select `item_id` from inventory where `gebruiker_id` = ?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt-> bind_param('i', $gebruiker->id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($item_id);
    $items = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $items['item_id'] = $item_id;
    }
```

Inventory Table

```
    gebruiker_id |   item_id
__________________________
    1        |      1
    1        |      2
    1        |      3
    1        |      4
    1        |      5
    1        |      6
    1        |      7
    1        |      8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting the same element in the array each time...try:

```
 $items[] = array('item_id' => $item_id);
```

Comment: Still only returns 8.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Although gebruiker_id is a user, so it has to fetch the values for the currently logged in user and the values differs per user, this user has 8 items and another user has 6 items so BETWEEN won't work. when i try to run the query in PHPmyAdmin it returns 8 rows.

Comment: Yeah i just noticed that, and deleted the misleading SQL ...I would debug by adding a "count" variable inside of your while loop and making sure that the loop is looping 8 times. It's possible your $stmt->fetch() is not returning the expected number of rows

Comment: I tried debugging as you said and it count returns 8 so the loop is working fine.

Comment: Alright, for debugging try adding this to the interior of your loop:  $items_debug[] = $++count;   what is the value of $items_debug after the loop runs?

Comment: Result: `Array ( [0] => [1] => 1 [2] => 2 [3] => 3 [4] => 4 [5] => 5 [6] => 6 [7] => 7 )`

Comment: Good! Try making the entirety of your loop interior: $debug_items[] = $item_id;   what is the value of debug_items after it runs?

Comment: Result: `Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 [4] => 5 [5] => 6 [6] => 7 [7] => 8 )` Really weird, it seems like there is something wrong because when i change $debug_items to $items it doesn't work and when i change it to $items_db it works. Strange..

Comment: You are perhaps overwriting $items somewhere else, glad you got it figured out!

Comment: Thanks for the help! I appreciate it. Now when we're still talking, as i said I'm quite a noob in PHP and MYSQL can i ask you some more questions for my project ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68674/discussion-between-stlmikey-and-j-koppen).

Answer (score 3):

You keep overwriting the value of `$item['item_id']` in your loop. What you're probably looking for is:

```
$items[] = $item_id;
```

That will capture all of the item IDs in an array.

Comment: Doesn't give me a return at all... EDIT: it did but still it only returns 8

Comment: I'm wondering if the OP started the session or not, and if it has any bearing on the issue.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Since they do get one row I am assuming their query is running successfully

Comment: @JohnConde That's correct, when I run the query trough PHPmyAdmin it returns 8 rows with the correct values.

Comment: Gotta be the fetch method then.